# HTML images are not loading

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a php laravel website on linux pc. I'm just trying to develop frontend view with simple html, css, js & bootstrap. I have store images inside `home/kunchana/blog/images`. When I'm link an image to website & preview it in localhost images are not loading only alt text is appearing.

I have tired same simple html code on a windows pc too. same results. Images are not loading.

```html
<img src="/images/web.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle margin" style="display:inline" alt="ME" width="350" height="350>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Think you could put those images in the www folder like www/youproject/images 
and also your php in www/youproject/

Comment: can you please explain me further

Comment: Your image folder must be in the same root folder

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a comment so i will drop an answer straightforward.

Depending on your directories hierarchie make sure to add/remove backslashes within the url depending on where your index.php file and your images are located.

Please let me know if it works then.